# Como configurar WCF para recibir JSON por POST

Tags: json, wcf, http-post

estoy tratando de consumir un servicio de WCF, para guardar una entidad.
tengo la sig. clase en WCF:

```
public class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CodigoRespuesta { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
public class RespuestaCliente:Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public int idCliente { get; set; }
}
```

He visto que para aceptar solicitudes de angular se configura un Global.asax (que en teoría le indico que headers y contenido puede aceptar). tengo en el BeginRequest:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";/*forzando el encabezado */
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Pragma, Cache-Control");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
           // HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

Para indicar que reciba json utilizo el WebInvoke y el Format.JSON pero no parece reconocer el ContentType en mi servicio,siempre espera un 'text/xml'

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "AltaCliente")]
    RespuestaCliente AltaCliente(Cliente ocliente);
```

Sin embargo, mi aplicación siempre arroja esto en consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

indico el link de video para comprobar la interacion con mi app:
http://srecorder.com/s/9cms

pues hasta ahora probé agregando: `<services> <service name="Wcf_PlanesSeguros_TDD.PlanSeguros"> <host> <baseAddresses> <add baseAddress="localhost:10442/PlanSeguros" /> </baseAddresses> </host> <endpoint address="localhost:10442/PlanSeguros/AltaCliente" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="Wcf_PlanesSeguros_TDD.IPlanesSeguros" /> </service>` arroja: "500 (System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException)" con esa misma puse Address="" y tampoco.
La sig config. es una actualización de hoy 06/Julio/2020 14:50,

```
    <system.serviceModel>    
        <services>
      <service name="Wcf_PlanesSeguros_TDD.PlanSeguros" behaviorConfiguration="Service">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:10442/PlanSeguros" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration ="BasicHttpBinding_IPlanesSeguros"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Wcf_PlanesSeguros_TDD.IPlanesSeguros"></endpoint>
        <!-- <endpoint address=http//localhost:10442/PlanSeguros/AltaCliente -->
        <endpoint address="rest/AltaCliente" bindingConfiguration="enlaceHttpRest" behaviorConfiguration="webRest"
binding="webHttpBinding"
    contract="Wcf_PlanesSeguros_TDD.IPlanesSeguros" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <!--2° los behaviors-->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webRest">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service">
          <!--Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca los valores siguientes en false antes de la implementación-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!--Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <!--3°los bindings-->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPlanesSeguros"
                     maxBufferSize="92160"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="92160" 
               textEncoding="utf-8"
            transferMode="Buffered">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="92160" 
                    maxStringContentLength="92160"/>
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      
      <webHttpBinding>       
     <binding name="enlaceHttpRest"
        closeTimeout="01:10:00" 
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="92160" 
             maxBufferSize="92160">
  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="92160" 
                    maxStringContentLength="92160"/>
     </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>     
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="http" />
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

pero al acceder a Servicio.svc en navegador se queja del wraped como si no lo hubiera puesto,aunque tengo claramente especificado:

[WebInvoke(Method ="POST",RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "AltaCliente", BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

Comment: Tenes configurado el webConfig de tu WCF? y me parece que es necesario un parametro que te falta para configurar el body

Comment: De hecho intenté usando <system.webServer><httpProtocol><customheaders><add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers .. ......</customheaders>" que preácticamente realiza lo mismo que el .asax,pero no me funcionó,ahora no tengo configuración especial en web.config, según leí o lo hago por programación o lo hago por configuración,

Comment: Agrega tu web.config la parte de Service

Comment: Tenes que agregar tu actualizacion en la pregunta no como comentario. Para que un servicio use wcf funcione como rest hay que configurarlo bien.

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu servicio WCF funcione como Rest, debes configurarlo en el webconfig.

Primero podes crear el endpoint, dejo un endpoint para `soap` y el que tiene `Addres="rest"` es para `Rest`, observa que cambia el `Binding`, se le agrega un `BehaviorConfiguration` y el `BindingConfiguration`, controla la cantidad de info que se puede enviar, el timeout, etc. Eso podes dejarlo de lado por ahora.

```
 <service name="ServicioWCFSeguridad.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Service">
        <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServicioWCFSeguridad.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="rest" contract="ServicioWCFSeguridad.IService1" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="enlaceHttpRest" behaviorConfiguration="webRest"/>       
      </service>
```

Despues tenes que crear los Behaviors

```
 <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webRest">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

y por ultimo de dejo un ejempo de los Bindings para que veas como se crean y configuran. Veras que tienen Timeout, cantidad de bytes para enviar, un tipo de Binding y un nombre para que sea llamado por el endpoint.

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
               maxBufferSize="2147483647"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               textEncoding="utf-8" 
               transferMode="Buffered">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="enlaceHttpRest" 
             closeTimeout="01:10:00" 
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: ok, @Ramiro Barone , pero me genera una ultima duda ,entonces el Address="rest" lo remplazo por mi url : address="http://localhost:10442/PlanSeguros" o ya no uso mi url?

Comment: lo acabo probar como sugieres, pero a la hora de clickear en el PlanSeguros.svc en el navegador arroja: La operación 'CrearPoliza' del contrato 'IPlanesSeguros' especifica varios parámetros en el cuerpo de la solicitud que se van a serializar sin elementos contenedor. Como mucho, uno de los parámetros del cuerpo se puede serializar sin elementos contenedor. Quite los parámetros adicionales del cuerpo o establezca la propiedad BodyStyle de WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute en Wrapped

Comment: Te falta en la interface,   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "AltaCliente")] agregarle el parametro BodyStyle

Comment: tu url la seguis usando, pero si queres usarlo mediante Rest, para rest tu url terminaria http://localhost:10442/planseguros/rest/AltaCliente

Comment: Lo del atributo WebInvoke, lo tengo y todo, pero lo comenté en mi ultima prueba y aquí el detalle https://youtu.be/DQ-Kcq0em_c  de que tampoco cambió el comportamiento. Igualmente te agradezco por el tiempo para ayudarme, solo quedaría modificar mi url como comentas, realmente dudo que sea posible

Comment: le agregaste el BodyStyle en el webInvoke? y la url cambia para rest, porque es otro endpoint el que usas. Si le colocas res/help en la url, deberias ver las direcciones de tu servicio para que veas la direccion exacta a la cual debes consultar.

Comment: BodyStyle?, claro desde el inicio, nunca pude ver el res/help . Lo mejor será montar una WebAPI, ahí si me llegó a funcionar con javascript